# How to get store_id when user select any store (or store view) from store switcher from cms(content) page filter option (admin) in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento2

I want `store_id` in `vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/RosourceModel/AbstractCollection.php` in below method

```
protected function joinStoreRelationTable($tableName, $linkField)
{
    if ($this->getFilter('store')) 
    {
          // Here i want store_id ; 
    } 
}
```

because i want to get my custom collection and want to assign in grid inside above method (this is the concept of UI)- Magento 2.1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f5kz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check the same function you will get to know

```
print_r($this->getFilter('store')->getData());
```

```
Array
(
    [field] => store
    [value] => Array
        (
            [in] => Array
                (
                    [eq] => 1
                )
```

`)

[type] => public`

)

Comment: When i have placed the above code in my same method at that Warning message has been displayed Something went wrong

Comment: before applying filters write the above code then apply filters and debug.

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i have done as you have suggested at that time one Warning message is displaying like Something went wrong 
and buffering(loading) page.